# How to explain "I think it should be tore down" is incorrect

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Please help me explain to a non-English speaker why "I think it should be **tore** down" is incorrect and she should say instead "I think it should be **torn** down." She thinks since the object is still standing, the past tense of "tear" (torn) should not be used. I can't find a way to explain why this seeming logic is incorrect.

Comment: I know this isn't an actual explanation, but maybe a parallel example would help: you wouldn't say *I think it should be **did*** but *I think it should be **done***, right? Well, *did* and *tore* are equipollent preterite forms, whereas *done* and *torn* are past participles. However, the person you're trying to explain this to might've actually heard *tore* as the past participle of *tear* from a speaker of a non-standard English dialect (such as *black English*).

Answer (score 3):

*Torn* is not the past tense of *tear*: it is the past participle. (The past tense is *tore*.)

And that name, ‘past’ participle, is not descriptive, only a historical accident: English participles in fact have **no** tense. In most contexts it might better be named a *passive* participle, because the English passive is constructed with *BE*+‘past’ participle; or a *perfect* participle, because the English perfect is constructed with *HAVE*+‘past’ participle.

The ‘past’ participle is obligatory in those constructions, but it does not indicate any particular time reference; only the first auxiliary in a verb group bears tense—

- It **is** torn down ... ‘present’ passive
- It **was** torn down ... ‘past’ passive
- He **has** torn it down ... ‘present’ perfect
- He **had** torn it down ... ‘past’ perfect

And of course even in these constructions the terms ‘past’ and ‘present’ (and, for that matter, ‘tense’) are not always appropriate: the ‘present’ may have future reference, and the ‘past’ may have present reference with the shift indicating some degree of unreality. This is most evident with modal verbs, whose ‘past’ forms have nonpast irrealis reference more often than not:

- It **should**<sup>(past)</sup> be torn down  *means tearing it down has not yet happened but is a desirable future project*.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'perfect participle' is now the construction of 'having+past participle'.

Comment: @user178049 I call that a 'participial perfect (and *to have*+PaPppl is an 'infinitival perfect'). ... And of course 'perfect' itself is another one of those wholly misleading Latin inheritances.